# How to break clipboard into multiple strings in Microsoft Word Using a VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I'm trying to replace multiple "placeholders" in a single word document by breaking the text in my clipboard into various string.

Sample clipboard text would be something like this:

```
Placeholder1=
Test1

Placeholder2=
First sentence.

Second Sentence.

Third Sentence.

Placeholder3=
2044 to 2045

Placeholder4=
five
```

So far, I can take the text my clipboard and paste it to replace a single placeholder. I can also insert the date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Sub FillPlaceHolder()

        'Prints a new label in bottom left of sticker sheet based on clipboard data
        'To use the clipboard you need a reference to the following library
        'Go to Tools > References and select Microsoft Forms Object Library
        'If it's not visible, click browse and find FM20.dll in your system32 folder
        Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
        Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

        'Set error handling, will skip the code if the clipboard is empty
        On Error GoTo Error

        'Set variable for clipboard string
        Dim myString As String
         Dim myDate As Date

        'Get data object from clipboard
        DataObj.GetFromClipboard


        'Set mystring to the first text in the clipboard
        myString = DataObj.GetText(1)
        myString = ClearFormatting




        'Open the Word document
        Documents.Open FileName:=GetFolder() & "Auden_perm_template.doc"

        'Replaces the PlaceHolder text
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "PLACEHOLDER2"
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = myString
            .Execute
        End With
        Selection.Paste

    TodaysDate2
    InsertDate
    TodaysDate
    InsertDate

    '


        'BELOW TO ADD PRINT
     '      Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), Name:="Print_Label"


    'Process this error for empty clipboards
    Error:
       If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Data on clipboard is empty"


    End Sub




Sub TodaysDate2()
'
' Macro3Date Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "TODAYSDATE2"
        .Replacement.Text = "02/25/19"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "TODAYSDATE2"
        .Replacement.Text = "02/25/19"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

End Sub
Sub InsertDate()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldDate
End Sub

Sub TodaysDate()
'
' Macro3Date Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "TODAYSDATE"
        .Replacement.Text = "02/25/19"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "TODAYSDATE2"
        .Replacement.Text = "02/25/19"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to break the clipboard into multiple strings. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can break the string into an array using `Split`

For example:

```
myString = split(DataObj.GetText(1),vblf)
```

Change the `Dim` for `myString` from `String` to `Variant`

Then you can loop through the array with something like:

```
For X = lbound(myString) to ubound(myString)
    If myString(X) = "PLACEHOLDER1" then
        'Do Something when placeholder1 found
    ElseIf myString(X) = "PLACEHOLDER2" then
        'Do Something when placeholder2 found
    ElseIf myString(X) = "PLACEHOLDER3" then
        'Do Something when placeholder3 found
    End IF
next
```

You will need to `Dim` `X` as a `Long`

You can set up a couple of variables to set the start and end of each placeholder then you can cycle through those parts joining each element back together with a `vblf` as the delimeter in order to create what you want.